# mysql syntax error store procedure

Tags: mysql, syntax, procedure

I'm trying to create a procedure but its get an error.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4.

Line 4 is "INSERT INTO TB...."

```
  DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS simpleproc;
  CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (IN p_cd_empresa INT, IN p_cd_servico INT, IN p_cd_concessionaria VARCHAR (100))
      BEGIN
         IF p_cd_servico = 1 OR p_cd_servico = 3 OR p_cd_concessionaria = 'GESTAO' THEN
             INSERT INTO TB_EMPRESA_IMPORTAR VALUES (p_cd_empresa, p_cd_servico, p_cd_concessionaria);
         END IF;
      END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put another delimiter than `;` for multi-statement procedures / functions.

```
  DELIMITER $$
  DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS simpleproc;
  CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (IN p_cd_empresa INT, IN p_cd_servico INT, IN p_cd_concessionaria VARCHAR (100))
      BEGIN
         IF p_cd_servico = 1 OR p_cd_servico = 3 OR p_cd_concessionaria = 'GESTAO' THEN
             INSERT INTO TB_EMPRESA_IMPORTAR VALUES (p_cd_empresa, p_cd_servico, p_cd_concessionaria);
         END IF;
      END;
  DELIMITER ;
```